# How I can create LVM VDO volume on top of LVM RAID?

Tags: linux, raid, storage, lvm, vdo

Im using LVM to setup my lower level storage with raid5 via `lvcreate --type raid5 --size 2T -I 256K -i 3 -n my_lv my_vg`

Now I want to setup VDO on the top of this using LVM too. Im aware of [this man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmvdo.7.html#VDO_Topics) but I tried `lvconvert --type vdo-pool -V 20T my_vg/my_lv` just ending with no raid.

If I use PV on top of my raid LV to setup VDO would get a fully functional dmeventd stack with vdo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* have a RAID-protected LVO volumes, but `lvm` itself is not so clear in reporting it.

I tried with a CentOS 8.2 box and a RAID1 LVM volume, converting it to a `vdo-pool` type with the following command: `lvconvert --type vdo-pool -n VDOLV -V 1G vg_test/lv_test`

How to check if RAID1 is working? You need to pass some additional options to the command line. Executing `lvs -o +seg_type -a` resulted in:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvs -o +seg_type -a
  LV                       VG      Attr       LSize  Pool    Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Type
  root                     system  -wi-ao---- 50.00g                                                        linear
  swap                     system  -wi-ao----  7.90g                                                        linear
  VDOLV                    vg_test vwi-a-v---  1.00g lv_test        0.00                                    vdo
  lv_test                  vg_test dwi-------  8.00g                37.62                                   vdo-pool
  [lv_test_vdata]          vg_test rwi-aor---  8.00g                                       100.00           raid1
  [lv_test_vdata_rimage_0] vg_test iwi-aor---  8.00g                                                        linear
  [lv_test_vdata_rimage_1] vg_test iwi-aor---  8.00g                                                        linear
  [lv_test_vdata_rmeta_0]  vg_test ewi-aor---  4.00m                                                        linear
  [lv_test_vdata_rmeta_1]  vg_test ewi-aor---  4.00m                                                        linear
```

Note the `raid1` segment type. And `dmsetup table` shows (again, see the RAID `rimage/rmeta` devices):

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmsetup table
vg_test-lv_test_vdata_rimage_1: 0 16777216 linear 230:16 10240
vg_test-lv_test-vpool: 0 2099200 vdo V2 /dev/dm-6 2097152 4096 32768 16380 on auto vg_test-lv_test-vpool maxDiscard 1 ack 1 bio 4 bioRotationInterval 64 cpu 2 hash 1 logical 1 physical 1
vg_test-lv_test_vdata: 0 16777216 raid raid1 3 0 region_size 4096 2 253:2 253:3 253:4 253:5
vg_test-VDOLV: 0 2097152 linear 253:7 1024
vg_test-lv_test_vdata_rimage_0: 0 16777216 linear 230:0 10240
vg_test-lv_test_vdata_rmeta_1: 0 8192 linear 230:16 2048
system-swap: 0 16572416 linear 8:2 104859648
vg_test-lv_test_vdata_rmeta_0: 0 8192 linear 230:0 2048
system-root: 0 104857600 linear 8:2 2048
```

Finally, I removed a block device and tryed to re-import the pool - it succeeded (with a warning about the missing device):

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvs -o +seg_type -a
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 8jLeqt-TRKt-IVHy-JP0g-mAta-XL2k-cXpEdF.
  WARNING: VG vg_test is missing PV 8jLeqt-TRKt-IVHy-JP0g-mAta-XL2k-cXpEdF (last written to /dev/zd16).
  LV                       VG      Attr       LSize  Pool    Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Type
  root                     system  -wi-ao---- 50.00g                                                        linear
  swap                     system  -wi-ao----  7.90g                                                        linear
  VDOLV                    vg_test vwi-a-v-p-  1.00g lv_test        0.06                                    vdo
  lv_test                  vg_test dwi-----p-  8.00g                37.63                                   vdo-pool
  [lv_test_vdata]          vg_test rwi-aor-p-  8.00g                                       100.00           raid1
  [lv_test_vdata_rimage_0] vg_test iwi-aor---  8.00g                                                        linear
  [lv_test_vdata_rimage_1] vg_test Iwi-aor-p-  8.00g                                                        linear
  [lv_test_vdata_rmeta_0]  vg_test ewi-aor---  4.00m                                                        linear
  [lv_test_vdata_rmeta_1]  vg_test ewi-aor-p-  4.00m                                                        linear
```

So, it should work. However, RAID and VDO are relatively recent addition to LVM (which, by the way, is growing in complexity) and care should be taken when mixing different segment type. For that reason I generally use plain `mdadm` to create the software RAID array, layering LVM on top of it.

If you want, post the output of `lvs -o +seg_type -a` to let me (and other) examine your LVM setup after creating the RAID and VDO volumes. Anyway, be sure to triple-check your RAID setup before putting any valuable data in your volumes.

Comment: not sure if this still works for raid5. the reason for my doubt is I have seen stripes as parameter for vdo volumes. I will try it